# How to use the Google cloud platform service account key generated using serviceAccounts.keys.create API, at the client side in Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-api-java-client, service-accounts

I am using the service account key generated in GAE using the `serviceAccounts.keys.create` Google IAM API at the client side to upload files to GCS. This API returns `privateKeyData` field which I am using in the client side code as follows:

```
public class GCSTest {
    public static final String CLOUD_STORAGE_SCOPE =
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform";
    private GoogleCredential credential = null;
    private HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = null;
    private Storage storage = null;
    private final JsonFactory json_factory = JacksonFactory
            .getDefaultInstance();
    public String APPLICATION_NAME = "GCSTest";
    private String privKeyString =
            <copy the privateKeyData from response of serviceAccounts.keys.create>;

    public void startTests() {
        initStorageService();
        writeObject();
    }

    private void initStorageService() {
        List<String> scopeList = new ArrayList<String>();
        scopeList.add(CLOUD_STORAGE_SCOPE);
        HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        byte[] privKeyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(privKeyString.getBytes());
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privKeyBytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(spec);
        credential =
            new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
                .setJsonFactory(json_factory)
                .setServiceAccountId(
                        "<service_account_name>@<project-id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
                .setServiceAccountScopes(scopeList)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(privateKey)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyId(
                        "<key_id>")
                .build();

        storage =
            new Storage.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, json_factory,
                credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }
    private void writeObject() {
        String fileName = "StorageSample";
        Path tempPath = Files.createTempFile(fileName, ".txt");;
        Files.write(tempPath, "Sample file".getBytes());
        File tempFile = tempPath.toFile();
        tempFile.deleteOnExit();

        InputStreamContent contentStream =
                new InputStreamContent("text/plain", new FileInputStream(
                        tempFile));
        contentStream.setLength(tempFile.length());
        StorageObject objectMetadata = new StorageObject().setName(fileName);
        Storage.Objects.Insert insert = 
            storage.objects().insert(<bucket_name>,
                        objectMetadata, contentStream);;
        insert.setName(fileName);
        insert.execute();
    }
}
```

However, I get `java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format exception` when `storage.objects().insert` is called.
Is this the correct way of using the service account key to generate the `GoogleCredential`?
P.S: I know about the JSON or P12 key file. I don't want to use it since it doesn't fit my use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the password for the private key string generated using `serviceAccounts.keys.create` is `notasecret`. The following code gets the `PrivateKey` from the `privateKeyData` field from the API response. This `PrivateKey` can be used to obtain `GoogleCredential`

```
byte[] privKeyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(privKeyString.getBytes());
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
ks.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(privKeyBytes), "notasecret".toCharArray());
PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey("privatekey", "notasecret".toCharArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, `serviceAccounts.keys.create` generates a GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_FILE, which is a JSON document describing the key and some other things. Clients like [gcloud-java](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.2.7/index.html) can read those files, like so:

```
StorageOptions options = StorageOptions.builder().projectId(PROJECT_ID)
    .authCredentials(AuthCredentials.createForJson(
          new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_JSON_KEY))).build();
Storage service = options.service();
```

Your code, though, is expecting a p12 key file. You could extract the key in the JSON file into such a format, but an easier way would probably be to call `serviceAccounts.keys.create` with the `serviceAccountPrivateKey` parameter set to `TYPE_PKCS12_FILE`.

Comment: Thank you. I generated the key using `TYPE_PKCS12_FILE`, but now I am getting `java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : version mismatch: (supported:00,parsed:03` error.